# Bernoulli (Binary Data) algebra with logs

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Came across this,

$\phi =$ probability of event

$p(y,\phi) = \phi^y(1-\phi)^{(1-y)} = Exp(\log(\phi^y(1-\phi)^{(1-y)}))$ and now, somehow $Exp(\log(\phi^y(1-\phi)^{(1-y)})) = Exp[\log(\frac{\phi}{1-\phi})y + \log(1-\phi)]$. I looked to use the power rule for logs to bring down the $y(1-y)$ in front, the product rule for logs to get an addition to the equation, and the subtraction rule for logs to get the division part of the expression. Upon simplifying, I don't yield the desired expression

My attempt is shown below:

\begin{align}
Exp(\log(\phi^y(1-\phi)^{(1-y)})) &= Exp[(1-y)\log(\phi^y(1-\phi))] \\ &= Exp[(1-y)\log(\phi^y) + \log(1-\phi)] \\ &= Exp[(1-y)y\log(\phi) + \log(1-\phi)] \\
\end{align}

So, now I'm not sure if this can arrive at the right answer

Comment: $\log a^x = x \log a$ and $\log ab = \log a + \log b.$ You are somehow using $\log a^x b = x (\log a  + \log b).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try not to skip any steps -
\begin{align}
p(y,\phi)  &=  \phi^y(1-\phi)^{(1-y)} \\
&= \exp\lbrack \log [ \phi^y(1-\phi)^{(1-y)}]\rbrack\\
&= \exp\lbrack \log(\phi^y)+\log((1-\phi)^{(1-y)})\rbrack\\
&= \exp\lbrack y\log(\phi)+(1-y)\log(1-\phi)\rbrack \\
&= \exp\lbrack y\log(\phi) - y\log(1-\phi) +\log(1-\phi)\rbrack \\
&= \exp\lbrack y(\log(\phi) - \log(1-\phi)) +\log(1-\phi)\rbrack\\
&= \exp\lbrack y\log(\frac{\phi}{1-\phi}) +\log(1-\phi)\rbrack\\
\end{align}